# Web service design - error code (store in source code or store in database?)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Web service error response (code/message etc) would you store it in a database? or would you keep the error response in a method.

By the time I'm done with this, there will be hundreds of error response, maybe in the future, thousands? (I dont know yet, depends how large this web service grows).

EDIT: error response is the response returned back to the application via the web service, (not to be confused with error logging).

Comment: How often will the existing ones need to be updated?

How often will new ones be added?

How often will they be accessed - every transaction or only when a transaction goes bad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error codes aren't designed to look good in UI when something goes wrong. Their main goal is to inform application what happened so that application could react.

If you move the error codes to the database you'll not be able to handle them unless you'll make a standard procedure of handling EVERY error code (for example log it and shutdown the application).